# ARMA and differencing time series, Theory questions

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima

True/False Statements, if false make them true:

1.The model Y<sub>t</sub> = Y<sub>t-1</sub>
+ u<sub>t</sub>, where u<sub>t</sub> is a white noise process, is a process whose logarithm is stationary.

**My idea:** So the model itself is not stationary since its a random walk, but if i take the logarithm that should change right?

2.
The model Y<sub>t</sub> = Y<sub>t-1</sub>+δ+ u<sub>t</sub> , where u<sub>t</sub> is a stationary ARMA(1,1) process with E(u<sub>t</sub>)=0,
models a time series where the growth rates ∇Y<sub>t</sub> are uncorrelated

No idea if the second one is true.

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume you mean second order stationary.  If $Y_t$ is not second order stationary, it is because the mean and/or variance change overtime. If that be the case, I see no way the mean and/or variance of $\log(Y_t)$ could remain the same.
2. Growth rates as you define them are $\delta + u_t$. Take the particular case $\delta=0$ to make things simpler: that leaves you with $u_t$ which, being ARMA(1,1), is not an uncorrelated process.